# jquery Deferred execution order

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

```
var d1 = $.Deferred();
var d2 = $.Deferred();

d1.resolve( "Fish" );
d2.resolve( "Pizza" );

// adding callbacks
$.when( d1, d2 ).done(function ( v1, v2 ) {
    console.log( v1 ); // "Fish"
    console.log( v2 ); // "Pizza"
});
```

Here in above example, even though the callbacks have been added after both the deferreds are resolved (instantly) but still it prints "Fish" and "Pizza" on the console.

Can somebody explain this to me, where I am going wrong?

Code snippet source: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: You're not going wrong. That's exactly how this should work. What am I missing?

Comment: Yeah a deferred represents an async process/task/promise/whatever. It's just a messenger that tells you where the task is at. In your case, it's done.

Comment: @johnnyfun--You are absolutely correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior and nothing is wrong.  If you add a `.then()` handler to a promise that is already resolved, it will still call the `.then()` callback you just added according to the state of the promise you added it to.

The same is true for `$.when()`.  Even though both the promises you pass it are already resolved, it will still call the `.then()` handler you add to the promise that `$.when()` returns.

Promises "remember" their resolved/rejected state so it can be easily accessed by them even after it is already resolved/rejected.

One important feature of promises is that you can add `.then()` handlers and they will be called if/when the promise is fulfilled - whenever that happens (immediately, sometime in the future or never).  You, the developer using a promise do not have to worry about the timing of the fulfillment, including whether it has already happened.  Regardless of the timing, your code will execute the same.  That's the beauty of promises.